# Object recognition kitchen - linemod

Tags: ros, object-recognition-kitchen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

i have installed the linemod package. Now i want to recognize an object (i already have a 3d mesh of it). How do i do that?
On http://wg-perception.github.io/linemod/index.html#line-mod it is said that i need an *automatic view generator* in order to convert my mesh into a `*.bag` file which i then can upload into the database via `object_recognition_capture upload` command.

Where do i get this automatic view generator from?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63611/object-recognition-kitchen---linemod/) by [rosfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4992/rosfan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2013-05-27

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe it is the ork_renderer package

---

Originally posted by [Aly](https://answers.ros.org/users/5191/aly/) with karma: 56 on 2013-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0